# Windows Local Administrator Account

Tags: windows

Would the local administrator account on Windows server be considered a user account or a system account similar to "root"?

Comment: The difference is academic, especially any comparison to *nix account structures. This smells like a badly worded homework problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's a user account; there are some things that "Administrator" cannot do that "LOCAL SYSTEM" can do.